# Schema.org BlogPosting and image required

Tags: images, blog, schema.org

I am trying to mark a blog with schema.org metadata (using Microdata).

I have tested with the test tool at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ and I get an error saying:

> *image:   missing and required*

I am using [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) schema, but I have pages without images.

**Why is an image mandatory** and **what should I do if I don't have one**? Is it okay to have no tag, or is there some way to show there is no image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Schema.org does not require any properties, so having a `BlogPosting` without an `image` property is totally fine. (And, other than omitting the property, there is no way to denote that you don’t have an image.)

(I’d even guess that not providing an image would be the norm, as the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) is *not* for just any image that is contained in the blog post, but for an image *of*, or an image that *represents*, the blog post itself.)

The fact that Google reports this error in their [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) does not mean that the code would be invalid or that you would have to fix anything. (Ideally Google would mark these as informational, or warnings, but not as errors.)

It just means that Google won’t provide an [Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) for your blog post in their results, as the `image` property is required for that, according to their documentation.

If you just want to check your Microdata and don’t care about Google-specific stuff (like their Rich Snippets), have a look at alternative tools: [Online Microdata parser (Software Recommendations SE)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13674/60).

Comment: Okay, I figured it was a bit of a strange requirement and had noted Yoast of WordPress SEO fame had the validation errors on his own blog site.

Comment: Additionally, if you do wish to gain Rich Snippets, without including the image on the page, you could use the JSON-LD format which is detailed here also: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles