# Impact of not filling image attribute in article schema or filling a constant one

Tags: images, schema.org, amp

We have an existing site with thousands of articles without images.

Google are [saying](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#amp) that an `image` attribute for the `Article` schema of AMP pages is required. Additionaly said:

> Only a marked-up image that directly belongs to the article should be specified.

We don't have budget to illustrate all those articles. What would be the impact of not adding that attribute, or to fill it with a constant image?

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83300/schema-org-blogposting-and-image-required?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Maximillian! I didn't find it while pre-searching answer to my question! We also want to know what is the impact of using a constant image. Would google ignore us or something...